# Column not showing up in list settings page but present in view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a column "Version" in a list that is showing up in the views but the column is not listed in the settings page under "Columns" section. I'm able to see it in quickedit but it is defaulting to "1.0" and not allowing me to edit.

I have tried setting "Yes" to "Allow management of content types?" but the column still does not show up. Appreciate if someone can help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version is a default list column, it does not show up in the List Settings page, it only shows up in the Views. When versioning is not enabled on your list, it will always show version 1.0, otherwise it reflects the actual document version.

If you don't want it in the view, simply edit the view and deselect Version and it will not show up any more.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response Eric! Now it makes sense. I have created my own version column to set versions manually as the default column updates version even if we do a minor change.